# How to make tkinter window/screen modular

Tags: python, tkinter, python-module, python-class

I am trying to make a Tkinter app, but I would like to make my app modular.
By that I mean I want a common "screen = Tk()" in a class but I want to add other items to it through different python files and classes.

My current code
file 1-

```
from tkinter import*


class screen:
    def __init__(self,screen):
        self.tk = Tk()
        Myitem = screen(screen)
        self.tk.mainloop()
```

file 2-

```
from screen import*

def items():
    button = Button(text="Test")
    button.pack()
App = screen(items)
```

But when I run the file all I get is the blank Tk window.

Basic question: How to make a Tkinter screen modular

Comment: Don't you think that `screen(screen)` is bit weird? If file 2 is executed, I got exception `TypeError: items() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` on the line `Myitem = screen(screen)` instead of a blank window as you said.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.